# How to handle primary key updating issue for offline app with Realm?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, realm, offlineapps

I am working on an app that offers offline functionality as well. 
The workflow of my app is similar to the following:

1- User creates a new object in the database while offline

2- This object gets a temporary (negative) id, as the app does not yet know what 
     final id the server will assign to the object

3- User/app syncs the database when online again

4- The server receives the new object and assigns a final id to it

5- The app receives the final id from the server and updates the objects id to the final one

I am using realm database which don't allow to update primary key. I want your suggestion regrading this problem that how to handle this situation.﻿

Comment: Could there be more than one user being interested in the same data, or is it possible that a user deletes his local data and must get data from the server again?

Comment: @CL. The problem is that the one table record  is connected with the whole DB. If user don't go online for days and user creates hundreds of  the offline records and these records are dependent on other records as a whole tree is created.

Comment: I was not asking about that, but whether there is synchronization of new data from the server to the client.

Comment: Yes there is synchronization of new data .

Answer (score 1):

Your app already has a function to download new data from the server, which you can reuse:
After the app has uploaded all temporary objects to the server and the server has confirmed that it has stored them, just delete all temporary objects from your local database, and do a server→client synchronization.

Alternatively, don't use temporary objects, i.e., change the primary key so that it already is unique when your app creates it; the Realm documentation [recommends](https://news.realm.io/news/realm-primary-keys-tutorial/) that

> you use a string property since it’s easier to generate values that are guaranteed to be unique (Especially with the UUID classes in the Apple and .NET frameworks).

Answer (score 0):

Use @PrimaryKey on id which you want to treat as primary key.

Comment: I am not asking about setting primary key. Please look at the question again to understand the problem

Comment: Sorry, I thing you need to delete all temporary id's items from db then insert new items. You can't update primary key.